# OSx Mountain Lion ssh-askpass

Tags: macos, cocoa, ssh

In OSX Lion (10.7.x) i was able to write an SSH wrapper that used ssh-askpass to input my password for SSH servers, but now with Mountain Lion (10.8) I am unable to use this method. I was wondering how it has changed  or how I could set it up to use this again. Some of my clients do not have it setup for me to use a rsa key.

Comment: Well, I figured out how to do it without ssh-askpass, I finally broke down and use sshpass. Not really that big of a deal. I am however, still curious if there is a way to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this blog that contains a simple shell script implementing ssh-askpass.  It works for me for accessing Mercurial repositories over SSH from GUI applications.

http://blog.retep.org/2009/04/09/ssh-askpass-on-osx-10-5/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah that works up until 10.8, now 10.8 doesn't even try to use ssh-askpass.

Comment: With Sourcetree and with Netbeans the script version of ssh-askpass from that blog works for me on 10.8.  Sorry it wasn't a help for you.